# javascript getelementbyID does not return value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am using javascript to get the value of a `hiddenfield`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            var newYear = document.getElementById('HF');
            alert('hehe' + newYear);
            $('#countdown').countdown({ until: newYear, format: 'DHMS', layout:
'<div id="timer">' + '<hr />' +
    '<div id="timer_days" class="timer_numbers">{dnn}</div>' +
    '<div id="timer_hours" class="timer_numbers">{hnn}</div>' +
    '<div id="timer_mins" class="timer_numbers">{mnn}</div>' +
    '<div id="timer_seconds" class="timer_numbers">{snn}</div>' +
'<div id="timer_labels">' +
    '<div id="timer_days_label" class="timer_labels">days</div>' +
    '<div id="timer_hours_label" class="timer_labels">hours</div>' +
    '<div id="timer_mins_label" class="timer_labels">mins</div>' +
    '<div id="timer_seconds_label" class="timer_labels">secs</div>' +
'</div>' +
'</div>'
            });
        });
</script>
```

This is the aspx code

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div class="maindeal">
            <input type="hidden" runat="server" id="HF" />
                <div class="SocialNetworkShare">
                    <asp:Label ID="SocialNetworkShare" runat="server" Text="Share" CssClass="SNS"></asp:Label>
                </div>
```

Code Behind[I am setting the value for the hidden field in code behind]

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If IsPostBack = False Then
            ShowOfferDetails(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("DefaultOffer"), True)          '... here "0;0;0" is given as there is no event argument
        End If
        HF.Value = "10/21/2011"
        MsgBox(HF.Value)
    End Sub
```

The problem is javascript doesnot detect this value...and throws null exception when i use `alert()` to check the value.....please help.

Comment: please check the error console and verify is their any error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HF control is server side and hence its ID in DOM will not be just HF.
What you can do is put a `class="HF"` attribute in the HF control and then from JS you can do
`$(".HF").val()` to get its value

Comment: hey it works but the javascript doesnot calculate the time correct...HF has a value of 2011/10/22 ..but the timer shows 34 mins left..it should show 2 days some hours some mins left.

Comment: Please refer to the `countdown` API doc. The until parameter expects different format that what the HF text value is

Comment: How can i change its format to "mm/dd/yyyy"? [This is the link to the plugin](http://keith-wood.name/countdownRef.html)

Comment: `var dt = newYear.split('/');` Then `until : new Date(parseInt(dt[0]), parseInt(dt[1]) - 1, parseInt(dt[2]))`

Comment: :) Thanks mate :) You saved a lot of time for me. :)thanks again.

Comment: How can i use this script 3 times on my page??

Comment: declare the function outside of `$()`, give the function a name, call the function any times you want to

Comment: Yes, make this a general function which you can call from anywhere including from `$()` as you want it to call multiple times. Also you would need to pass "#countdown" value as paramater so that you can create as many countdowns

Comment: hey are ya from india ...if yes drop me a mail at monodeep12@gmail.com...i need to tell ya something...[Check This Link](http://coders.tricedeals.com).

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
 var newYear = document.getElementById('<%=HF.ClientID %>'); //It return Html object
 alert(newYear.value);

 //OR

 var newYear1 = document.getElementById('<%=HF.ClientID %>').value;
 alert(newYear1);
```

Comment: This does not work :( i get `objectHTMLInputElement` in the msg box.

Comment: @SifyJuhy - Use newYear.value or var newYear = document.getElementById('<%=HF.ClientID %>').value;

Comment: hey it works but the javascript doesnot calculate the time correct...HF has a value of 2011/10/22 ..but the timer shows 34 mins left..it should show 2 days some hours some mins left.